# How to write binary data to stdout in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, stdout, qdatastream, qtextstream

`QTextStream` allows me to wrap `stdout` so that I can write using Qt spesifics to stdout with conveneince. Example:

```
QTextStream qout(stdout);
qout << QString("Some qt spesific stuff: %1\n").arg(1337);
```

However while `QTextStream` is really useful, it does not support binary data. All data that passes through it is expected to follow valid character sets and encodings (unicode/UTF-8 etc).

So the logical replacement if I want to output raw binary data to `stdout` would be to replace `QTextStream` with `QDataStream`. However that class does not allow me to wrap `stdout` (it has no constructors that takes std file handle).

So what options do I have for having "Qt convenience" while writing binary data to `stdout`? And what would be next best thing?

PS: I know writing binary data to std out is not always good idea. However, I really need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open stdout with [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) overload of `QFile::open` like this:

```
QFile my_stdout;
if (my_stdout.open(1, QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QDataStream qout(my_stdout);
    qout << QString("Some qt spesific stuff: %1\n").arg(42);
}
```